# can't instantiate class

Tags: c++, class, instantiation

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. I'm not going to show the full creation of my main function because I don't think it will matter.

My issue has to do with this class that I create:

```
class employee
{
    //create private variables for divider
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    char gender;
    int dependants;
    double annualSalary;
    static int numEmployees;

public:

    Benefit1 benefit;

    employee()
    {
        //create default values for varaibles
        firstName = "not given";
        lastName = "not given";
        gender = 'U';
        dependants = 0;
        annualSalary = 2000;
    }

    employee(string first, string last, char gen, int dep, double salary, Benefit1 ben)
    {
        //allow input
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        gender = gen;
        dependants = dep;
        annualSalary = salary;
        benefit = ben;
    }
}
```

(Yes, Benefit1 was properly called in the class.) My problem comes when I try to instantiate it as employee2:

```
employee employee2("Mary", "Noia", 'F', "5", 24000.0, benefit1);
```

For some reason my program will not allow me to put ANYTHING in the first instance where the word "Mary" is. As you can see the first instance is suppose to be string first, so why isn't it letting use anything?

Comment: In the Ctor, shouldn't "5" be 5 since the Ctor is expecting an int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the fifth parameter - it's expecting an `int` and you'r epassing it `"5"`. Try:

```
employee employee2("Mary", "Noia", 'F', 5, 24000.0, benefit1);
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. Not sure why my system highlighted "Mary".

Comment: I remember why I made that mistake. My assignment for class required me to write some funny setters for dependants and annualSalary. Numbers had to be entered as string and then converted into the appropriate type. Confusing and unnecessary, yes, but I suppose it teaches us how to use conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter which you are passing has to be an `int`:-

```
employee employee2("Mary", "Noia", 'F', 5, 24000.0, benefit1);
```